# Font Times New Roman 11,25 Regular is not supported in telerik reporting

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

I'm having some trouble exporting to PDF in Telerik Reporting Q2 2008.

It seems that for some reason, exporting to PDF ( or printing, which is the same, it first exports to PDF, and then prints ), is giving me this error.

First it started with Arial, I found the bug with the font Arial, replaced the textbox with Times New Roman, and it keeps on giving me this error.

The strange thing, is that this only happens on the production server ( Windows Server 2008 ), on my development machine, this works flawlessly, I even tried to copy the fonts from my windows font folder, to my production server, but that didn't help anything...

Does someone know what is happening?

EDIT: Problem solved...a server reboot solved the problem instantly, unfortunately at the time I posted this question I couldn't do a server restart, later that day ( at night ) my boss restarted the server and all was good again..

Thanks all..

Comment: What is "this error"?  Read this: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/export-to-pdf-throwing-error.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.. it was that error exactly... I finally managed to solve it, by doing a restart on the production server.. Thanks anyway..